# Is it possible to get Google Error Reporting available in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, error-reporting, google-cloud-error-reporting

Google has the Error Reporting service https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting

Is there a way to integrate this into Grafana? - I could not find a Plugin for this data.

Or is there an alternative to this data source within Grafana?

Comment: Stackdriver does not do what you want? https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/google-cloud-monitoring/

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer - currently using that data source, but not sure how to get the Error Reporting data.

Comment: Perhaps the solution is to create my own Query from the log data